# Strange C# GUI+ issue: image re-sized when drawing under 120 dpi

Tags: c#, gdi+

I experienced a strange image drawing issue in C# when setting dpi to 120. The image we created in run-time got re-sized in another Image object when we proform this code:

```
        if ((dstimg == null) || srcimg == null)) return;
        Graphics dstg = Graphics.FromImage(dstimg);
        dstg.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        dstg.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;// = dst.smooth;
        dstg.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        dstg.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        dstg.DrawImage(srcimg, x, y);
        dstg.Dispose();
```

The srcimg is:
[image]

And dstimg is:
[image]

This problem would not show if the Windows Aero feature is on, since the dpi in Aero is always 96px. But once we turn off Aero, the problem would show.

I have no idea about what was wrong. The DPI for both source image object and destination image object are 96 dpi. Can anybody give me a hint about what may happened?

Comment: Seems like GDI+ is [full of bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515995/how-to-find-out-more-about-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi). I suggest using another library.

Comment: @HansPassant both Image objects are 96px, and this is still in memory, not on monitor.  We copied this image multiple times with nearly identical code, only at this stage, the problem would show. I believe there could be a setting issue in destination image, but were never able to find it.